# ERROR: Render problem y Tablayout en Android Studio

Tags: android, studio

Cuando creo un TabItem dentro de un Tablyout me generan errore; además, no me permite ver la visualización del diseño debido al error.

**1. Render problema:** `Style ResourceReference{namespace=apk/res-auto, type=attr, name=textAppearanceButton} is not of type STYLE (instead attr)`

**2. Render problem:** `Failed to find style with 2131033031`

**3. Render problem:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException   at android.content.res.Resources_Theme_Delegate.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources_Theme_Delegate.java:74)   at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1631)   at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:874)   at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:3965)   at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTextAppearance(AppCompatTextView.java:216)   at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.setTextAppearance(MaterialTextView.java:106)   at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:3954)   at androidx.core.widget.TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(TextViewCompat.java:289)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.updateTab(TabLayout.java:2772)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.update(TabLayout.java:2801)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.setTab(TabLayout.java:2713)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:1673)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.newTab(TabLayout.java:956)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addTabFromItemView(TabLayout.java:824)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addViewInternal(TabLayout.java:1730)   at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addView(TabLayout.java:1720)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1131)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
```

**4. No speakable text present:** `This item may not have a label readable by screen readers.`

A continuación presento el código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:tabIconTint="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/yellow"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/yellow"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabcategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabhome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Home"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabreciente"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reciente"/>

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, haz podido resolverlo??

Comment: Me esta pasando exactamente lo mismo con el TabLayout....

Answer (score 0):

Tuvo el mismo problema y lo resolví cambiando la versión de **MaterialDesign** a

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

Las versiones más recientes de **MaterialDesign** están dando ese problema. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Estas seguro que esto funciona? Por qué cambiar a esa versión que tiene esta versión?

Comment: Si, recién estuve empezando un nuevo proyecto y me tope con ese problema del TabLayout, lo que hice fue bajar la versión del materialdesign y funciono. Las versiones más recientes no son recomendables utilizar ya que son más propensas a presentar fallas, siempre es recomendable usar dos o tres versiones menos a la actual.

Comment: ¿entonces cuando es recomendable actualizar?

Comment: Cuando la versión que estas utilizando queda obsoleta o cuando la nueva versión tiene algo que requieres para tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

tuve el mismo problema y lo solucione agregando lo siguiente:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'//Para solucionar el problema del TabLayout
```

y comentando el material por defecto

```
// implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
```